# How do I decode my HTTP Get request with a JSON body in Swift 5?

Tags: json, swift, httprequest, httpresponse, decodable

I'm trying to get data from a response. On the RapidAPI page, I tried the GET requests, and also in the app I get a response. But it will not decode the JSON to my Decodable protocol. I've done it before for weather and locations, but it just seems it doesn't fit this time.

```
class ClubManager {
    func getClubInformation(clubID: String) async throws -> Club? {

        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://transfermarket.p.rapidapi.com/clubs/get-squad?id=\(clubID)") else {fatalError("Missing URL")}

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        urlRequest.setValue("transfermarket.p.rapidapi.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-rapidapi-host")
        urlRequest.setValue("006f5b3a01mshaa222632dd44131p17cc4djsn9e2c7e927b93", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-rapidapi-key")

        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {fatalError("error fetching data")}
        
        print(response)

        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data)
        
        
        return decodedData
        
    }
}

struct Club: Decodable {
    
    var mainFacts: MainFacts
    var stadium: Stadium
    
    struct MainFacts: Decodable {
        var id: String
        var fullName: String
        var city: String
        var coutryImage: String
        var squadSize: String
        var avgAge: String
    }
    
    struct Stadium: Decodable {
        var id: String
        var name: String
        var totalCapacity: String
        var image: String
    }
    
}
```

The API says I get this response body:

```
{
    "internationalTeamFlag":"",
    "mainFacts":{
        "id":"44",
        "fullName":"Hertha Berliner Sport-Club",
        "street":"Hanns-Braun-Straße, Friesenhaus 2",
        "postalCode":"14053",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "phone":"+49 30 300928",
        "fax":"+49 30 300928",
        "homepage":"www.herthabsc.de",
        "founding":"25.07.1892",
        "members":"37800",
        "membersDate":"01.07.2020",
        "countryName":"Deutschland",
        "countryID":"40",
        "countryImage":"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/flagge/verysmall/40.png?lm=1520612525",
        "avgAge":"26.20",
        "squadSize":"30",
        "legionaries":"16",
        "internationalRank":"",
        "nationalPlayer":6
    },
    "stadium":{
        "id":"343",
        "name":"Olympiastadion Berlin",
        "street":"Olympischer Platz",
        "postalCode":"14053",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "phoneTicketCenter":"+49 30 3009280",
        "faxTicketCenter":"+49 30 30092899",
        "homepage":"www.olympiastadion-berlin.de",
        "ticketCenter":"www.eventim.de/tickets.html?fun=erdetail&affiliate=OLY&doc=erdetaila&erid=470534",
        "constructionYear":"1934",
        "totalCapacity":"74649",
        "standingRoom":"0",
        "seats":"74649",
        "image":"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/foto/stadionnormal/olympiastadion-berlin-1587729679-37029.jpg?lm=1587729699"
    },
    "historicImages":[
        0:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597300.png?lm=1400597299",
        1:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597307.png?lm=1400597306",
        2:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597316.png?lm=1400597315",
        3:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597323.png?lm=1400597322",
        4:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597332.png?lm=1400597331",
        5:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597346.png?lm=1400597345",
        6:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597356.png?lm=1400597355",
        7:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597368.png?lm=1400597367",
        8:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1400597374.png?lm=1400597374",
        9:"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44_1502534268.png?lm=1502534269"
    ]
    "successes":[
        0:{
            "number":"2",
            "name":"Deutscher Meister",
            "id":"10",
            "additionalData":{
                "competitionId":"L1",
                "competitionTypeId":"1",
                "cycle":NULL,
                "seasonIds":[
                    0:"1930",
                    1:"1929",
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
    "additionalTeams":[
        0:{
            "image":"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/44.png?lm=1534505742",
            "name":"Hertha BSC",
            "id":"44"
        },
        1:{
            "image":"https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/medium/45.png?lm=1562952802",
            "name":"Hertha BSC II",
            "id":"45"
        }
    ]
    "share":{
        "title":"Vereinsprofil Hertha BSC",
        "url":"https://www.transfermarkt.de/hertha-bsc/startseite/verein/44",
        "description":"Dies ist die Vereins-Startseite. Hier gibt es neben dem aktuellen Kader vereinsrelevante News, aktuelle Gerüchte und alle wichtigen Infos rund um den Spielbetrieb des Klubs."
    }
}
```

This is the Error:

```
Error getting Club: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "mainFacts", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"mainFacts\", intValue: nil) (\"mainFacts\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: The error says there is no Club, and there isn't.

Comment: What is `ResponseBody`? Is `"x-rapidapi-key"` value your own private key? If yes, you might want to hide it.

Comment: the json data you show is not valid json. Fix this first, then you'll have a chance to decode it. Mainly to do with missing commas and the arrays.

Comment: Also, you have `coutryImage` instead of `countryImage` in `MainFacts`. Show us the real json data, not what you think it is supposed to be.

Comment: To show what you get from the server, do this (then show us):
     After `let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)`
     add `print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")`

Comment: I did make a wrong GET request. And the countryName was wrong aswell. Now it works. Thanks @workingdog

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `ResponseBody` is but I would try and
change

```
    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data)
```

To

```
 let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Club.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten to refactor